# universal Thread method

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hello everyone I want to ask , is there any methods that using thread that can run every methods[B] with argument and return any kind of those methods[B] refer :

```
private static Image queeImageFromString (string str)
{
    // bla bla
    return myImage;
} ///methods B return image

private static byte[] queeImagetoBtye (string str, string b)
{
    //bla bla
    return myBytesArray;
} //methods B return image

//**this is the methode I want to ask** 
private static dynamic RunMethods(Action action)
{
    var file;
    var thread = new Thread(() => { file = action; });
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    return file; //will return anything like string, image, bytearray depending on method[B] returne
    /// note : this code still wrong 
} 

/// I want to do 'RunMethods' run like this
public static string getResultByte (string str, string b)
{
    // if methods[B] return string it will return string 
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder (RunMethods(queeImagetoBtye (str,b));
    return strb.ToString();
}

public static Image getImageResult (string str)
{
    //if methods[B] return Image it will return Image
    Image imgs = RunMethods( queeImageFromString (str));
    return imgs;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working cause of many reasons.

1. `Action` can't return anything, it's an action, you have to use `Func`
2. You do not call the action, just assign it, so you have to write this code: `file = action();`
3. You're creating the action from lambda wrong way, you need to do like this: `() => queeImageFromString(str)`
4. Not a major problem, but you don't have to create a `StringBuilder` to create a string, you can return the method result itself.

What you need is a `generic` method, as dynamic is very slow structure, and dealing with it always relates with a reflection, which is slow by default. You can provide the type for function to return, like this:

```
private static T RunMethods<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    var file;
    var thread = new Thread(() => { file = f(); });
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    return file; //will return anything like string, image, bytearray depending on method[B] return value
}
```

So the call will looks like this:

```
//if methods[B] return Image it will return Image
Image imgs = RunMethods<Image>(() => return queeImageFromString(str));
```

Maybe the call could be even more simplified, but right now I can't check that. Also you really should consider the TPL usage instead of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Check if doing it another way would be suitable for you.

I would create a class containing returned values, together with some indicator saying what type of object I'm returning.

```
public class ReturnValues
{
    public object ReturnValue;
    public ReturnValueType RetType;
}

enum ReturnValueType
{
    typeOfString,
    typeOfImage,
    typeofInt
}

public static ReturnValues queeString (object[] args)
{
    //.....
    return new ReturnValues{ ReturnValue="Test",  RetType=ReturnValueType.typeOfString };
}
```

Now, instead of Action, you have to use Func.
If you have to take parameters, you have to take them in some object too, like object array object[].

```
public static ReturnValues RunMethods(Func<object[],ReturnValues> action)
{
    var file=action;
    //.....
    return file;
}



public static string getResultByte (object[] args)
{
    string str=(string)args[0];
    string b=(string)args[1];
    var initValue=RunMethods(queeString(args));
    string returnedString;
    if (initValue.RetType==ReturnValueType.typeOfString)
    {
        returnedString=(string)initValue.ReturnValue;
    }
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder (returnedString);
    return strb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it ...but is there any more simple than this ?